# Query on the base of relational data | Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, orm

I am looking for solution to get information on the base of relational table information for example

I have two models **User** and **Post**

**User** has many **Post** and
**Post** belongs to **User**

I want to get users those have **role = tasker** and have **posts** less then 5

please guide me how to do in **laravel 5.4**

Comment: Have you tried reading about queries first? I'm sure you can build your answer from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries)

Comment: yes i read the doc but couldn't find the solution like above i mentioned. can you please let me know the exact solution ? thanks

Comment: I can't give you the exact solution, but I'm assuming you must join with the post table use a group by and an having clause. Hopes this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am making some assumptions here about the structure of your database and field names but this should get you close:

```
User::whereHas('posts', function($query) {
      $query->select('posts.*')
            ->join('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->groupBy('users.id')
            ->havingRaw('sum(posts.id) < 5')
})->having('role', '=', 'tasker')->get();
```

Probably not exact but that is the gist of it.

Comment: Here how i did.
$users =  DB::table('users')
            ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(posts.id) as total_posts'), 'users.*')
            ->leftJoin('posts', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
            ->groupBy('users.id')
            ->having('total_posts', '<', 5)
            ->where('users.role', '=', 'tasker');